# Names imported into importer's scope in python

Tags: python, namespaces

There're two scripts:

```
#imptee.py
foo = "abc"

def show():
    print "foo from imptee:",foo
```

---

```
#impter.py:

#!/usr/bin/env python

from imptee import *

show()

foo = 123
 
print "foo from impter:",foo
show()
```

When I run impter.py, it yields the following result:

> foo from imptee: abc
>
> foo from impter: 123
>
> foo from imptee: abc

I just don't understand why after assigning 123 to variable foo, show() still print 'abc', not 123. I think after "from imptee import *", foo and show() are in global namespace now, and there are no local namespace. I do understand that the searching sequence should be: local namespace, global namespace, bulit-ins namespece. So, why is that? Could someone give me a hand, please?
THX!

Comment: Please put your code in a code block so it's easier to read

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll take care from now on. But I'm a new user, I don't know exactly how to do that, any more advice?

Comment: You can highlight your code and press the "code" button above the editing window to do it automatically, or you can simply indent all of your code four spaces (in addition to any other indentation it may have) to do it manually.  In this case, another editor has done it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules have separate namespaces.  When you import from one module to another, you are importing the values (usually functions but in this case a literal "abc") from the source module and assigning them to names in the destination module.

When you do `from imptee import *`, you are assigning them to the same name that they had in the source module, but that doesn't actually change the pointers in the source module.  It just duplicates the names.

When you change the assignment in the destination module after the import, that doesn't change anything in the source module, because even though the names look the same they are separate pointers and can point to separate things.

This might be more clear if you did `import imptee` and then manually assigned the value: `foo = imptee.foo`.  Then later you'll do `foo = 123`, and it makes sense that the value of foo in the destination module has changed but the value of the similarly-named pointer in the source module has not.

Comment: WOW, get it, thanks a lot, and one more question please. Why show() chooses the foo("abc") in imptee, not the one in impter(123)? I just don't understand this

Comment: In the impter namespace you import `foo` and `show`.  foo points to a string and show points to a function on the imptee module.  You change the impter.foo name to point to 123, but the imptee.foo name still points to "abc".  imptee.show and impter.show both point to the same function, a function on the imptee module.  When show() is called, it uses the imptee module namespace to find foo().  There is no way for an imptee module to get the the impter module's version of foo except by importing it (circular imports are bad!) or having it passed as an argument to show().

Comment: Totally understand! Thanks again for your patience and help :)

Answer (score 3):

What is called the "global namespace" in Python is actually the *module* namespace. Each module has one, and they are independent. Therefore, importing `*` from `imptee` copies the *object references* from `imptee` into `__main__`; `imptee` still has its own namespace even after the fact, which `show()` has a reference to regardless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean there're actually two foos right? But show() has to search variable foo, right? Then what foo it just uses, "abc" or 123? According to the result, it uses "abc", but why?

Comment: Because `show()`'s global namespace is `imptee`, not `__main__`. Importing it from `imptee` does not change this.

Answer (score 1):

Because the statement `from imtee import *` is (approximately) the same as `from imptee import foo`, which is also (approximately) the same as `import imptee; foo = imptee.foo`. So `foo` doesn't change in `imptee` for the same reason that assigning the same value to two variables then changing one of those variables doesn't change the value in the other:

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> b = a
>>> a
'hello'
>>> b
'hello'
>>> b = 'world'
>>> a
'hello'
>>> b
'world'
```

Additionally, as other answers have noted, the "global" namespace is actually "global to the module", not "global to all modules". Global variables in other modules can be changed by importing the module then setting the corresponding attribute: `import imptee; imptee.foo = "bar"`.